# Prevent Foundation button text from changing color on click

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, button, zurb-foundation

I am working with Foundation in a Rails app, and I have some buttons.

When I click a button, the text inside the button changes from white to grey, because it is remembering that I have previously clicked that button before.

I do not want this to happen. I want the button text to remain white all the time.

So how can i disable this feature of the text color changing after a button has been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I just found it.

In the CSS you add

```
.button_visited
{
   color: white;
}
```